# Vue.js in .jinja template for Pyramid project

Tags: python, vue.js, jinja2, pyramid

I wanna to use vue.js in my .jinja template for  Pyramid project, but i can't.
If i understand correctly vue.js running only on .html files. What i must to do?

signin.jinja2

```
<body>
<div id="id">
    <p> {{ title }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
new Vue({
el: '#id',
data: {
    title: "hello world"
}})
```

signin.py

```
@view_config(route_name='signin', renderer='../templates/signin.jinja2')
def sign_in(request):
return{}
```

This code return nothing on my page.

---

UPD: i think that i found decision [here](https://github.com/eddyekofo94/pyramidVue), but i don't understand how it's work. Need some tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand what is happening where - your Pyramid app is basically a program which gets a text blob as its input (request) and returns another text blob as its output (response). When received by the browser, the response text blob is interpreted, in this case, as an HTML page, with all its script tags etc. The browser then executes the javascript which only has access to the DOM which is generated from that HTML blob. The fact that your Pyramid app used a Jinja2 template to generate that blob is irrelevant at that point.

So now you can see that "vue.js in jinja2 template" is never actually happening - it's always "vue.js in HTML", and the only thing you need is to ensure your app outputs the correct HTML.

This may be a bit problematic in this particular case because both jinja2 and vue.js use `{{...}}` as text interpolation syntax. If you view page source in your browser you'll see that the `{{ title }}` bit got processed by Jinja2 and vue.js never sees it. You're basically generating one template from another template with a similar syntax.

I'm not super-familiar with either Jinja2 or vue.js, but I would try the following:

- Consider changing the templating library to something which syntax does not clash with vue.js. Maybe TAL or Mako.
- If you want to keep using Jinja2, you'll need some sort of function which outputs Vue.js markup from a Jinja template:

  ```
  def vue_markup(s):
      return '{{ ' + s + ' }}'
  ```

  which you would use in your template like this:

  ```
  {{ vue_markup('title') }}
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for something similar. Apparently jinja2 allows this using:

```
{% raw %}

Anything in this block is treated as raw text,
including {{ curly braces }} and
{% other block-like syntax %}

{% endraw %}
```

This seems to allow vue code to work correctly.

Comment: This certainly worked for me.